# Performance of dependent pre/post-incremented memory accesses

Tags: performance, arm, apple-m1, arm64

My question primarily applies to firestorm/icestorm (because that's the hardware I have), but I am curious about what other representative arm cores do too.  Arm has strange pre- and post-incremented addressing modes.  If I have (for instance) two post-incremented loads from the same register, will the second depend on the first, or is the CPU smart enough to perform them in parallel?

Comment: provide an example, pre and post increment have been around for decades not some arm thing btw....

Comment: naturally the processor is going to execute the instructions as specified by the programmer

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the exact behaviour of the M1 execution units is **mainly undocumented**. Still, there is *certainly* a **dependency chain** in this case. In fact, it would be very hard to break it and the design of modern processors make this even harder: the decoders, execution units, schedulers are distinct units and it would be insane to dynamically adapt the scheduling based on the instructions executed in parallel by execution units so to be able to break the chain in this particular case. Not to mention that instructions are pipelined and it generally takes few cycles for them to be committed. Furthermore, the time of the instructions is variable based on the fetched memory location. Finally, even this would be the case, the Firestorm documents does not mention such a feedback loop (see below for the links). Another possible solution for a processor to optimize such a pattern is to fuse the microinstructions so to combine the increment and add more parallelism but this is pretty complex to do for a relatively small improvement and there is no evidence showing Firestorm can do that so far (see [here](https://dougallj.github.io/applecpu/firestorm.html) for more information about Firestorm instruction fusion/elimitation).

The M1 big cores (Apple's Firestorm) are designed to be **massively parallel**. They have **6 ALUs per core** so they can execute a lot instructions in parallel on each core (possibly at the expense of a *higher latency*). However, this design tends to require a lot more transistors than current mainstream x86 Intel/AMD alternative (Alderlake/XX-Cove architecture put aside). Thus, the cores operate at a significantly **lower frequency** so to keep the energy consumption low. This means dependency chains are significantly more expensive on such an architecture compared to others unless there are enough **independent instructions** to be execute in parallel on the *critical path*. For more information about how CPUs works please thread [Modern Microprocessors - A 90-Minute Guide!](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/). For more information about the M1 processors and especially the Firestorm architecture, please read [this deep analysis](https://www.anandtech.com/show/16226/apple-silicon-m1-a14-deep-dive/2).

Note that Icestorm cores are designed to be energy efficient so they are far less parallel and thus having a dependency chain should be less critical on such a core. Still, having less dependency is often a good idea.

As for other ARM processors, recent core architecture are not as parallel as Firestorm. For example, the [Cortex-A77](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/arm_holdings/microarchitectures/cortex-a77) and [Neoverse V1](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/arm_holdings/microarchitectures/neoverse_v1) have "only" 4 ALUs (which is already quite good). One need to also care about the **latency** of each instruction actually used in a given code. This information is available on the ARM website and AFAIK not yet published for Apple processors (one need to benchmark the instructions).

As for the pre VS post increment, I expect them to take the same time (same latency and throughput), especially on big cores like Firestorm (that try to reduce the latency of most frequent instruction at the expense of more transistors). However, the actual scheduling of the instruction for a given code can cause one to be slower than the other if the latency is not hidden by other instructions.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question.  I think the question is whether something like `ldp x1, x2, [x0], #16 ; ldp x3, x4, [x0], #16` actually has a dependency chain in the first place, or if both loads can execute in parallel with reduced latency.

Comment: There is a dependency chain due to the increment (this was implicit in the answer). While Firestorm processors might be able to theoretically optimize that, I doubt this is the case since it would be pretty insane to implement in practice. But, as said in the answer, this is AFAIK undocumented. Still, I am not aware of any processor capable of breaking the dependency chain yet in this case. This is up to the programmer to do that. One solution is to unroll the loop using chunks of 4~8 iterations. This is important on Firestorm due to the very large buffers / OOO window (as explained).

Comment: @NateEldredge I edited a bit the answer to precise why it would be very unlikely for Firestorm to break the dependency chain and that there is no evidence showing that so far.

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer to this on IRC: such usage will be fairly fast (makes sense when you consider it corresponds to typical looping patterns; good if the loop-carried dependency doesn't hurt too much), but it is still better to avoid it if possible, as it takes up rename bandwidth.